# Need help understanding why calling multiple functions are returning the same values?! [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

so here is my code below. I kind of expected the three functions to return the following in order, as that would make logical sense as the functions were invoked in this order:

- [{First, false}]
- [{First, false}, {Second, false}]
- [{Change, false}, {Second, false}]

But that's not what happened...what ends up happening is I get the exact same return for all the functions!? Results as follows:

- [{Change, false}, {Second, false}]
- [{Change, false}, {Second, false}]
- [{Change, false}, {Second, false}]

How is this possible? Can anyone please explain what is going on?

Here is the code:

```
var todolist = {
    todos: [],
    displayt: function(){
        console.log(this.todos);
    },
    addTodo: function(todoText){
        this.todos.push({
            todoText: todoText,
            completed: false
        });
        this.displayt();
    },
    changeTodo: function(pos, todoText) {
        //this.todos[pos] = val;
        this.todos[pos].todoText = todoText;
        this.displayt();
    }

}

todolist.addTodo('First');
todolist.addTodo('Second');
todolist.changeTodo(0, 'Change');
```

Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bizkitgto/saqh5nrb/), and when I run it I open the console in Chrome to see the results.

THANKS!! THIS IS DRIVING ME INSANE

EDIT: OKAY! Looks like this is a chrome issue with console.log() and arrays/objects. If I modify the code (below) I can get the expected results, thanks u/jones1618

```
 var todolist = {

    todos: [],

    displayt: function(){
        for (var i = 0; i<this.todos.length; i++){
            console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);
        }
    },

    addTodo: function(todoText){
        this.todos.push({
            todoText: todoText,
            completed: false
        });
        this.displayt();
    },

    changeTodo: function(pos, todoText) {
        //this.todos[pos] = val;
        this.todos[pos].todoText = todoText;
        this.displayt();
    }

}

todolist.addTodo('First');
todolist.addTodo('Second');
todolist.changeTodo(0, 'Change');
```

Comment: Likely your console is merely giving you a late evaluated "live" version of the objects. The first call obviously ***cannot*** output "Second".

Comment: I don't see what you're seeing http://jsbin.com/cacidopube/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @evolutionxbox - open the console (dev tools in chrome) and run the fiddle, you'll see the output.

Comment: @deceze - is this a javascript quirk, I don't know why all the functions would have the same output...

Comment: @RyanL It's not a JS quirk, it's due to the console live evaluating the object when it's expanded. Instead log the `todoText` property.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - what do you mean 'log the todoText' property?

Comment: To test, you can replace console with alert. Then you can see that the values are coming correct

Comment: @RyanL inside `displayt` console log the property `todoText` of each todo item, instead of the object. This way you'll see that your code is working fine.

Comment: You can also try changing `console.log` to `console.table` or `console.dir` - you'll see that not only do these change the structure of the output, but also the time of evaluation/display.

Comment: All please see my edit. Thanks everyone for the help. This was making me nuts.